# How do I make the return value of a null function?

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization

I have a problem with the translation of a variable, I understand that the syntax is something like this:

```
loginButton(context) => Material(
  child: MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        const User().login(username: email, password: password).then((val) {
          if(val == "Success") {
            successRoute(context);
          }
          ScaffoldMessenger
              .of(context)
              .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text((val){
                switch (val){
                  case "dataIncorrectly":
                    return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.dataIncorrectly;
                  case "unexpectedResponse":
                    return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.unexpectedResponse;
                  case "connectionTimeOut":
                    return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.connectionTimeOut;
                  case "errorConnection":
                    return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.errorConnection;
                  default:
                    return "unexpectedError";
                }
              })));
        });
      }
    },
    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.signin)
  ),
);
```

I get an error: `The argument type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.`

I understand that the function should return a string, but I do not know the syntax. I don't want to output it separately as it won't be used in other places.

I tried to do:

`(){} as String`

`(){}.toString()`

Comment: By "null function", do you mean an *anonymous* function?  If you want to call an anonymous function, you just need to add a parenthesized argument list, as you would when calling any function.  In this case, your anonymous function doesn't need the `val` argument (it is already accessible from the outer scope), so it could be: `() { switch (val) { ... } }()`.

Answer (score 0):

jamesdlin's answer solved the problem
`(){switch...}()`
that's how the code worked. I didn't figure out how to specify the author of the comment here, so I just copied the nickname. Thanks jamesdlin